# IAsyncAction OnCompleted event handler called prematurely

Tags: c#, asynchronous, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

Something weird happening in my application and I cannot comprehend it. I create a background task for network communication using the ThreadPool class. In this task I call some methods asynchronously. The reason is that sometimes synchronous methods are not provided by Microsoft (for example there is not method DatagramSocket.Connect so I must use method DatagramSocket.ConnectAsync). But because I need to call these methods synchronously, I must use keyword "await" and mark the method as "async". When I do this, event handler for background task created in Button_Click event handler start is called prematurely. When the background task really finishes its job (for example by breaking the execution in debugger in manually moving execution pointer to the end of UdpSend method), OnCompleted event handler is not called. Is this normal ? Am I missing something important ?

```
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
   IAsyncAction work;

   public MainPage()
   {
      this.InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (work == null)
      {
         ButtonStart.Content = "Stop UDP test";
         work = ThreadPool.RunAsync(UdpSend);
         work.Completed = OnUdpSendFinish;
      }
      else
      {
         work.Cancel();
      }
   }

   private async void UdpSend(IAsyncAction work)
   {
      DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
      socket.MessageReceived += Socket_MessageReceived;
      HostName host_name = new HostName("10.0.0.2");
      await socket.ConnectAsync(host_name, "1234");
      DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
      uint data = 0;
      int payload_size = 512;
      int payload_len = payload_size / sizeof(uint);
      while (work.Status != AsyncStatus.Canceled)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < payload_len; i++)
         {
            writer.WriteUInt32(data++);
         }

         await writer.StoreAsync();
      }
   }

   private void Socket_MessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
   {
      throw new System.NotImplementedException();
   }

   private async void OnUdpSendFinish(IAsyncAction asyncInfo, AsyncStatus asyncStatus)
   {
      await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
          () =>
          {
             ButtonStart.Content = "Start UDP test";
          });
      work = null;
   }
}
```

Comment: The key is that `await` does *not* allow you to call them synchronously. They are still asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of how the await keyword works. It allows you to write all the code in the same method for readability, but in truth the method is split in two. Let's take a simple example:

```
private async void Example()
{
    DoSomething();
    await AsyncCall();
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

After compilation, the method is rewritten to something like (it's much more complicated):

```
private void Example()
{
    DoSomething();
    AsyncCall();
}

private void ExampleContinuation()
{
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

How the method is executed depends on what context it runs on. In your case, since you've used the thread pool, `Example` is run in the task you created (your `IAsyncAction`). After `AsyncCall`, the `Example` method returns, and so your `Completed` event is triggered. And only then, the runtime spins a new thread from the threadpool and uses it to run `ExampleContinuation`.

I workaround could be to use `Task.Run` instead of directly the threadpool. `Task.Run` will also use the threadpool under the cover, but with all the plumber y to handle those corner cases:

```
private Task work;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (work == null)
   {
      ButtonStart.Content = "Stop UDP test";
      work = Task.Run(UdpSend);
      work.ContinueWith(_ => OnUdpSendFinish());
   }
   else
   {
      work.Cancel();
   }
}
```

Then change the return type of your "UdpSend" method (it should have no incidence on the contents of the method, but it indicates the task that your call should be awaited):

```
private async Task UdpSend(IAsyncAction work)
```

Lastly, change the signature of your `Completed` handler:

```
private async void OnUdpSendFinish()
```

And you're done ;)